# Pandas/Python : How to add only one leading zero to a numeric column of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this: The Numbers column is a numeric column

| Numbers |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 567890 |
|  |
| 567 |

I want the output to look like this:

| Numbers |
| --- |
| 012345 |
| 0567890 |
|  |
| 0567 |

I tried numerous ways to do it, manually using excel also didnt help as it would go back to sqaure one after saving. Can someone please help with it?

Comment: do you want to keep the column as a numeric column?

Comment: Yes or anything is fine

Comment: so you don't have problems if it become a str column?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[12345,567890,567]})

df = '0' + df.astype(str)
```

**Output**

```
df
   Numbers
0   012345
1  0567890
2     0567
```

Comment: But when I write it back to csv file it loses that zero and empty values comes 0nan

Comment: @Sai are you using excel?

Comment: Yes . when I try to write it back to excel I loose the leading zeroes

Comment: @Sai try open it with notepad

Comment: I want to write the file to .csv

Comment: @Sai are you using `.to_csv`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. let say your dataframe is df, and column name that you want to add "0" is Numbers, so the script should be:

df['Numbers'] = '0' + df.Numbers.astype(str)